# Need a very simple Regualr Expression

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

I'm very week (actually I almost know nothing) about REGX. Its my week side. But I need a regular expression by which I'll work with my current project. My Texts are like this

```
\vspace{3pt} \noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{464pt}|}
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
1
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
কত ভাগ পানি প্রক্সিমাল প্যাঁচানো নালিকায় শোষিত হয়?
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
4
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৫৫\%
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৪৫\%
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৮০\%
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৬৫\%
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
3
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2pt}
```

You can see its latex. Now all i need is get the text between `\hline` & `\\`

So for example from the 3rd line to 6th line you can see it starts with `\hline` and ended with `\\`. I need the text between these. But I don't know the exact regular expression to get it. I tried some found in online and edit those, tried and failed since last 2 days.

Anyone here to help me giving correct regular expression? I'm working with PHP. The regular expression should return 8 text array from the given text above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to double escape the backslashes:

```
$in = <<<'EOD'
\vspace{3pt} \noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{464pt}|}
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
1
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
কত ভাগ পানি প্রক্সিমাল প্যাঁচানো নালিকায় শোষিত হয়?
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
4
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৫৫\%
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৪৫\%
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৮০\%
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৬৫\%
} \\
\hline
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
3
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2pt}
EOD;

preg_match_all('/(?<=\\\\hline)(?:(?!\\\\\\\\)[\s\S])+(?=\\\\\\\\)/', $in, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
1
} 
            [1] => 
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
কত ভাগ পানি প্রক্সিমাল প্যাঁচানো নালিকায় শোষিত হয়?
} 
            [2] => 
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
4
} 
            [3] => 
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৫৫\%
} 
            [4] => 
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৪৫\%
} 
            [5] => 
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৮০\%
} 
            [6] => 
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
৬৫\%
} 
            [7] => 
\parbox{464pt}{\raggedright 
3
} 
        )

)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\\\\hline)          # positive lookbehind, make sure we have \hline before
(?:                     # non capture group
    (?!\\\\\\\\)        # negaive lookahead, make sure we haven't 2 backslashes
    [\s\S]              # any character, including linebreaks
)+                      # end group, may appear 1 or more times
(?=\\\\\\\\)            # positive lookahead, make sure we have 2  backslashes after
```

Comment: Great, It seems its working. Let me check and as soon as its working, I'll accept it as answer. Thank you for your precious time. Please let me know if you ever need any help. I'll be glad to help

Comment: Hi, Can you modify the regx a little so that only I get the text in between, not with the marking text. meaning I don't want the starting `\hline` and ending `\\`